# Calculate euclidean distance in a faster way

Tags: r, performance, distance, missing-data, euclidean-distance

I want to calculate the euclidean distances between rows of a dataframe with 30.000 observations. A simple way to do this is the dist function (e.g., dist(data)). However, since my dataframe is large, this takes too much time.

Some of the rows contain missing values. I do not need the distances between rows, where both rows contain missing values, or between rows, where none of the rows contains missing values.

In a for-loop, I tried to exclude the combinations that I do not need. Unfortunately, my solution takes even more time:

```
# Some example data
data <- data.frame(
  x1 = c(1, 22, NA, NA, 15, 7, 10, 8, NA, 5),
  x2 = c(11, 2, 7, 15, 1, 17, 11, 18, 5, 5),
  x3 = c(21, 5, 6, NA, 10, 22, 12, 2, 12, 3),
  x4 = c(13, NA, NA, 20, 12, 5, 1, 8, 7, 14)
)


# Measure speed of dist() function
start_time_dist <- Sys.time()

# Calculate euclidean distance with dist() function for complete dataset
dist_results <- dist(data)

end_time_dist <- Sys.time()
time_taken_dist <- end_time_dist - start_time_dist


# Measure speed of my own loop
start_time_own <- Sys.time()

# Calculate euclidean distance with my own loop only for specific cases

# # # 
# The following code should be faster!
# # # 

data_cc <- data[complete.cases(data), ]
data_miss <- data[complete.cases(data) == FALSE, ]

distance_list <- list()

for(i in 1:nrow(data_miss)) {

  distances <- numeric()
  for(j in 1:nrow(data_cc)) {
    distances <- c(distances, dist(rbind(data_miss[i, ], data_cc[j, ]), method = "euclidean"))
  }

  distance_list[[i]] <- distances
}

end_time_own <- Sys.time()
time_taken_own <- end_time_own - start_time_own


# Compare speed of both calculations
time_taken_dist # 0.002001047 secs
time_taken_own # 0.01562881 secs
```

Is there a faster way how I could calculate the euclidean distances that I need?

Comment: dist is implemented in C, of course it is faster than an R for loop. You should implement your loop in Rcpp.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'll try to figure out how this works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you to use parallel computations. Put all your code in one function and do it parallel.

R will do all calculation in one thread by default. You should add parallel threads manually. Starting clusters in R will take time, but if you have large data frame, the performance of the main job will be (your_processors_number-1) times faster.

This links may also help: [How-to go parallel in R – basics + tips](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/) and [A gentle introduction to parallel computing in R](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2016/01/parallel-computing-in-r/).

Good choice is to divide your job into smaller packes and calculate them separately in each thread. Create threads only once, because it is time consuming in R.

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
# I am not sure that all libraries are here
# try ??your function to determine which library do you need
# determine how many processors has your computer
no_cores <- detectCores() - 1# one processor must be free always for system
start.t.total<-Sys.time()
print(start.t.total)
startt<-Sys.time()
print(startt)
#start parallel calculations
cl<-makeCluster(no_cores,outfile = "mycalculation_debug.txt")
registerDoParallel(cl)
# results will be in out.df class(dataframe)
out.df<-foreach(p=1:no_cores
                    ,.combine=rbind # data from different threads will be in one table
                    ,.packages=c()# All packages that your funtion is using must be called here
                    ,.inorder=T) %dopar% #don`t forget this directive
                    {
                      tryCatch({
                          #
                          # enter your function here and do what you want in parallel
                          #
                          print(startt-Sys.time())
                          print(start.t.total-Sys.time())
                          print(paste(date,'packet',p, percent((x-istart)/packes[p]),'done'))
                        }
                        out.df
                      },error = function(e) return(paste0("The variable '", p, "'", 
                                                          " caused the error: '", e, "'")))
                    }
stopCluster(cl)
gc()# force to free memory from killed processes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that helps me a lot! I did not even know that this is possible with R and will try to implement your solution!

Comment: I think `amap` package could be helpful here, if you don't want to create your own functions, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25767588/6327771) out