# in R, calculate a distance matrix CONTAINING NA's in parallel - NOT amap::Dist! on windows

Tags: r, parallel-processing, distance

Is there a way to calculate a distance matrix in Windows using multiple threads? I found this link:

[Parallel distance Matrix in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138179/parallel-distance-matrix-in-r)

but the bottom line was that Windows ignores the multiple threads option, and the fastest function was `dist.matrix` from the Wordspace package. Unfortuntately, it is unable to handle NA's like `Stats::dist` does, and `dist` becomes very slow for large matrices.

Comment: Closing as a duplicate since any answer to this should be an answer to the duplicate.

Comment: This is not a duplicate since the Original that you are referring to (which I am citing) doesn't discuss the case of NA's which is the most important feature for me.

Comment: The dupe asks to replicate `dist`, and `dist` works with NAs. If the accepted answer doesn't work with NAs you should comment on that there and then get a better answer.